# Hexafluorosilicid acid attacks glass?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, glass

When HF meets glass, Hexafluorosilic acid is formed (assuming some water is present). It appears that Hexafluorosilic acid and further attack glass? How is this so, considering that all F atoms are "used up" (already bonded to Si atoms)?

http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng1233.html

Comment: $\ce{H2SiF6}$ can decompose into HF in the presence of water fairly easily.  I wonder if HF is acting almost as a catalyst, with the fluoride chipping away at the glass, then breaking off, then chipping again, and so on.  If the hexafluorosilicic acid were put into water and started to decompose, it ought to provide a source HF to attack the glass, in the right environment.

Comment: So HF+SiO2 -> H2O*H2SiF6 (or something like that) is reversable?

Comment: Glass isn't exactly $\ce{SiO2}$, but that was my idea.  It would effectively be converting glass (big messy molecule that it is) into independent molecules of silicon dioxide.  To be clear, that was just my best guess.  I've never worked with the stuff and didn't find a mechanism for how it attacks glass when I looked.

Comment: @Jason: Glass dissolves (your term "independent molecules") up to 100ppm in water but could be more soluble in acid (but HCL would not attack glass due to the slow kinetics) Keep in mind "dissolve" actually indicates a reversable reaction, so it m

Comment: may need a catalyst to proceed to this equilibrium at a reasonable rate (they used finely divided particles). The fluoride probably increases the solubility.

Comment: Actually, Si-Cl bonds are unfavorible so HCl won't attack glass at all. However, Si-F bonds are not as unfavorable (compared H-F bonds).

Comment: yes, Jason Patterson might be right. $\ce{H2SiF6}$ decomposes to HF and  is further chips the glass. This whole process occurs spontaneously or within a short period of time. Because HF is concentrated, it almost readily form $\ce{H2SiF6}$ and whole process favours forward reaction and so the reaction is not reversible. btw $\ce{H2SiF6}$ is hexafluorosilicic acid.

Comment: @Jason If you let 70% HF eat as much glass as it can, then evaporated some HF (keeping [H2O] the same), the SiO2 would get super-saturated. Could this be used as a bath to coat things in glass/quartz?

Comment: @KevinKostlan It might work, but it seems like a fairly hazardous method, plus you'd only be able to coat things that were impervious to HF.  If you've never played with it, I would suggest buying a small quantity of sodium silicate (water glass.)  I've used it a number of times with it resulting in a glass-like coating on substances after it dries.  It would take some time to get the technique down, but it might be what you want.  It's also very safe if used with even a small amount of common sense.